# SSL Cert Verification Error hostname 'x.x.x' doesn't match either of '*exmple.com',

Tags: python, django, api, ssl, openssl

I'm working with many APIs, I send 200,000 requests per day and sometimes I get this error and don't know why:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='x.x.x', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/x/x/x/x (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname 'api.exmple.com' doesn't match either of '*.azureedge.net', '*.media.microsoftstream.com', 
'*.origin.mediaservices.windows.net', '*.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net'")))
```

When I was searching for the cause of this problem, I found many responses like you should change Verify =False and like you should add (ssl.match_hostname = lambda cert, hostname: True) But I am really not satisfied with this response because most of the requests are working fine.

```
 if 'Content-Type' in header and header['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
     if username and password:
                response = requests.request(http_method, url, json=data, headers=header, timeout=timeout,auth=(username, password),verify=True)
     else:
                response = requests.request(http_method, url, json=data, headers=header, timeout=timeout,verify=True)
```

Please help me and thanks

Comment: you're trying to connect to `api.exmple.com` but the certificate's subject alternative names (`*.azureedge.net`, `*.media.microsoftstream.com`, `*.origin.mediaservices.windows.net`, `*.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net`) do not contain a match to `api.exmple.com`

Comment: The problem is server side and cannot be fixed properly in the client. It is unclear if this happens with a server which was just working or with some new server. In the first case it might be some hiccup in the server like some load balancer were some instances are not properly setup. Or it might be someone fiddling with your network and trying DNS spoofing, or some hiccups in the DNS server. In the second case it is probably a wrong setup of the server,

Comment: Thank so much ,Do you know what type of expectation I have to put in this error to try sending the query again?